# print something when access to an attribute

Tags: python, getattribute

I am trying to print something when I am accessing to an attribute of a class by using `__getattribute__`
The big problem here is recursion and the fact I am overriding getattribute method.

I am afraid I have to use metaclass to solve this problem.
Anyway if you any answer of this problem.

Comment: Why are you using `__getattribute__` here at all? That method is called for *every attribute access*, so *including* `self.recursion`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters because it's the only way I know to access to existing attribute of A

Comment: But why do you need to override access to an existing attribute then? What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I just want to print "In class A" when I am accessing to a method of A (without defining it in each method).

Comment: And what is the `self.recursion` for?

Comment: You could also use decorators for your methods, of course.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3, btw?

Comment: My code is wrong. I remove it. Python 2.X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__getattribute__` is used for **all attribute access** on your instance. That includes `self.recursion` in that method.

You *rarely* need to use `__getattribute__`. If you do actually have a proper use-case for it, avoid attribute access or use `super(A, self).__getattribute__()` to avoid infinite recursion problems.

For your usecase (printing something whenever an attribute is being accessed), do use `super()` still to return the original attribute:

```
class A(object):
    def meth(self):
        return "met"

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        print "IN CLASS A"
        return super(A, self).__getattribute__(name)
```

Note that for `super()` to work you do need to use a new-style class, inheriting from `object`. If you are inheriting from something else, and that something else has a `__getattribute__` method, it is already a new-style class.

Comment: A derivates from another class which doesn't provide those method. Does it matter? I guess with polymorphism it will call subclass but we eenter in a recursion loop?

Comment: @Katsu: If `__getattribute__` already throws recursion errors for you, then that 'something else' is a new-style class. You can still use `super(self, A).__getattribute__(name)` in that case.